# Boolean comparision returns false when it should be true

Tags: c#, boolean

This is homework, heads up. I'm to write a card class, deck class, must have Equals(Deck aDeck), every 8 shuffle should perfectly match the original deck, print 20 iterations. I have my shuffle working - 8th and 16th shuffle is the same as the original deck, but the Equals class keeps returning false. I'm missing something and have been poring over this - can anybody guide me to my error? Thanks in advance!

```
namespace lab2part3
{
    public class DeckOfCards : Card
    {
        const int CARDS = 52;
        private Card[] cards;

        public void Deck()
        {
            cards = new Card[CARDS];
            for (int suitVal = 0; suitVal < 4; suitVal++)
            {
                for (int rankVal = 1; rankVal < 14; rankVal++)
                {
                    cards[suitVal * 13 + rankVal - 1] = new Card((Suit)suitVal, (Rank)rankVal);
                }
            }
        }

        public Card GetCard(int cardNum)
        {
            if (cardNum >= 0 & cardNum <= 51)
                return cards[cardNum];
            else
                throw (new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("cardNum", cardNum, "Value must be between 0 and 51."));
        }

        public void Shuffle()
        {
            Card[] newDeck = new Card[CARDS];
            bool[] assigned = new bool[CARDS];
            Random sourceGen = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {
                int destCard = 0;
                bool foundCard = false;

                while (foundCard == false)
                {
                    destCard = sourceGen.Next(CARDS);
                    if (assigned[destCard] == false)
                        foundCard = true;
                }
                assigned[destCard] = true;
                newDeck[destCard] = cards[i];
            }
            newDeck.CopyTo(cards, 0);
        }

        public void Faro()
        {
            Card[] firstDeck = new Card[26];
            Card[] secondDeck = new Card[26];
            Card[] finalDeck = new Card[CARDS];

            Array.Copy(cards, 0, firstDeck, 0, 26);
            Array.Copy(cards, 26, secondDeck, 0, 26);

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < CARDS; i += 2, j++)
            {
                cards[i] = firstDeck[j];
                cards[i + 1] = secondDeck[j];
            }
        }

        public bool Equals(DeckOfCards other)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CARDS; i++)
            {
                if (cards[i] != other[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        public Card this[int i]
        {
            get { return cards[i]; }
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
namespace lab2part3
{
    public class Card
    {
        public enum Suit { H, C, D, S }
        public enum Rank { _A = 1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _J, _Q, _K }
        public Suit suit { get; set; }
        public Rank rank { get; set; }

        public Card(Suit newSuit, Rank newRank)
        {
            suit = newSuit;
            rank = newRank;
        }

        public Card() { }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(rank.ToString());
            s.Remove(0, 1);
            return (s + "" + suit);
        }

        public bool Equals(Card other)
        {
            return rank == other.rank && suit == other.suit;
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
namespace lab2part3
{
    public class CardTester
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            DeckOfCards MyDeck = new DeckOfCards();
            DeckOfCards CopyDeck = new DeckOfCards();
            Card tempCard = new DeckOfCards();
            MyDeck.Deck();
            CopyDeck.Deck();

            // initial deck setup
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {
                tempCard = MyDeck.GetCard(i);
                Console.Write(tempCard.ToString());

                if (i != 51)
                    Console.Write(", ");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine();

                if (i == 12 || i == 25 || i == 38)
                    Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // 20 looped shuffles

            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                MyDeck.Faro();
                Console.WriteLine("\nShuffle #" + (j + 1) + ":\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
                {
                    tempCard = MyDeck.GetCard(i);
                    Console.Write(tempCard.ToString());

                    if (i != 51)
                        Console.Write(", ");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine();

                    if (i == 12 || i == 25 || i == 38)
                        Console.WriteLine();
                }

                // compare
                Console.WriteLine("does this deck equal the original deck? {0}", CopyDeck.Equals(MyDeck));

                // print original deck
                for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
                {
                    tempCard = CopyDeck.GetCard(i);
                    Console.Write(tempCard.ToString());

                    if (i != 51)
                        Console.Write(", ");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine();

                    if (i == 12 || i == 25 || i == 38)
                        Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `DeckOfCards` inherit from `Card`? A deck of cards is not a specialized type of card

Comment: I've done a refactoring of your code so that you can see how the code may be written - something to maybe learn from. It works correctly as described. You can find it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uUmStC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!=` operator you use in `cards[i] != other[i]` checks reference equality when used with reference types (unless you explicitly overload it). You already implemented a `Card.Equals` method, use it instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CARDS; i++)
{
    if (!cards[i].Equals(other[i]))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Instead of defining a new `Equals` method, you should override `object.Equals` method.
You can read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx) and [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) to get some more information about equality in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Change...

```
public bool Equals(DeckOfCards other)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CARDS; i++)
    {
        if (cards[i] != other[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

To this instead...

```
public bool Equals(DeckOfCards other)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CARDS; i++)
    {
        if (!cards[i].Equals(other[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Study up on proper ways to override object.Equals, and dealing the operator overloading for !=, etc.

Answer (score 0):

ok, first, your Shuffle method is super in-effective so I must fix it :

```
public void Shuffle()
        {
            Random sourceGen = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {
                Card temp = cards[i];
                int pos = sourceGen.Next(CARDS);
                cards[i] = cards[pos];
                cards[pos] = temp;


            }
        }
```

As to your question, you need to compare between the data of 2 objects.

```
for (int i = 0; i < CARDS; i++)
            {
                if (!cards[i].Equals(other[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

And third, `DeckOfCards` should not inherit from `Card`, they have no relation

Forth, the method `public void Deck` should be the constructor of `DeckOfCards`